# Error: UnsupportedOperation: This operation is not implemented

Tags: excel, office-js

`Chart.series` returns the result for specific types of charts (`Waterfall`, `Sunburst`):

> UnsupportedOperation: This operation is not implemented.

Is there a workaround or way to decipher the chart-type before the call?

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var seriesCollection = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").charts.getItem("Chart1").series;
    seriesCollection.load('items');
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < seriesCollection.items.length; i++) {
            console.log(seriesCollection.items[i].name);
        }
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```